# Error with the try-catch statements

Tags: java, exception, calculator

I need help fixing the try-catch statement so that it will handle the exception on the first try. At the moment, the exception handler only works on the second user input. I apologize in advance for my terrible wording.

```
class MyGradeLevels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Please enter your grade to begin!");

         java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
         double grade=input.nextInt();

         if ( grade >= 90 ) {
            System.out.println("Great Job!");
         } else if( grade <= 49 ) {
            System.out.println("Needs Improvement!");
         } else {
            System.out.println("Average Effort!");
         } 

        try { 
              grade=input.nextInt(); 
              System.out.println("Your Final Grade is "+grade); 
         } 
        catch( java.util.InputMismatchException e ) { 
              System.out.println("Please round your number and restart!"); 
         }

         input.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to wrap your `try catch` at the time of your *Please enter your grade to begin!* message?

Comment: yes sir! sorry about the wording, again.

Comment: Have you tried adding that code in a `try catch` block?

Comment: Move `try {` from where it is, to somewhere higher up in the code maybe?

Comment: i tried moving the try catch higher up but it still wouldnt work. I dont know much about java but i heard the exception handler had to be within the main code for it to work.

Comment: A `try` block only affects exceptions thrown from inside itself. If you want to handle exceptions from the line `double grade = input.nextInt()`, then that line must be inside a `try` block.

Comment: Don't move the `catch`.  Just the `try` and its `{`.  Put them above the line `double grade = input.nextInt();`, because that's the line that needs to be inside the `{ }`.

Comment: And there is no rule that says you can only handle exceptions inside `main`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the code written out and all. Either start the "try" earlier, orsurround the first input with the same exact try catch:

```
class MyGradeLevels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println("Please enter your grade to begin!");

         java.util.Scanner input=new java.util.Scanner(System.in); 
         double grade;
        try { 
              grade=input.nextInt();
              if ( grade >= 90 ) {
                 System.out.println("Great Job!");
              } else if( grade <= 49 ) {
                 System.out.println("Needs Improvement!");
              } else {
                 System.out.println("Average Effort!");
              } 
         } 
        catch( java.util.InputMismatchException e ) { 
              System.out.println("Your number isn't right.");

         }

        try { 
              grade=input.nextInt(); 
              System.out.println("Your Final Grade is "+grade); 
         } 
        catch( java.util.InputMismatchException e ) { 
              System.out.println("Please round your number and restart!"); 
         }

         input.close();     
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. `grade` in the second `try-catch` won't be recognized. Pull `grade` out of the first `try-catch` first

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want, but if not say...

```
class MyGradeLevels {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your grade to begin!");
    double grade = 0;
    try {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        grade = input.nextInt();
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please round your number and restart!");
    }
    if (grade >= 90) {
        System.out.println("Great Job!");
    } else if (grade <= 49) {
        System.out.println("Needs Improvement!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Average Effort!");
    }

    try {
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        grade = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Your Final Grade is " + grade);
        input.close();
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Please round your number and restart!");
    }

}
}
```